# What does it mean for a map to factor through another map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, function-and-relation-composition, morphism, coalgebras

In Darij Grinberg's "Hopf algebras in combinatorics", there is a statement about existence of quotient coalgebras:
"Indeed, $J ⊗ C + C ⊗ J$ is contained in the kernel of the canonical map $C ⊗ C → (C/J) ⊗ (C/J)$; therefore, the condition $∆(J) ⊂ J ⊗ C + C ⊗ J$ shows that the map $C → C ⊗ C \twoheadrightarrow (C/J) ⊗ (C/J)$ factors through a map $∆ : C/J → (C/J) ⊗ (C/J)$."

As far as I understand, "$f: A\to B$ factors through a set $S$" means "there exists a surjective map $\pi : A\to S$ and an injective map $i: S \to B$ such that $f=i \circ \pi$". But what does it mean for a map to factor through another map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map $f:A\to C$ factors through $g:A\to B$ if there exists $h:B\to C$ such that $f=h\circ g$. In such setup we also can say that $f$ factors through $h$. No surjectivity/injectivity conditions are required here, unless explicitly stated by the author. Which btw I don't think it is typically assumed for "factors through $S$" as well, but maybe someone does assume it.

Comment: But I don't believe it is possible to factor a map from $C$ through $C \otimes C$ to $C/J\otimes C/J$ into a composition, one of the factors of which is the map $C/J \to C/J \otimes C/J$. That would mean we need to either first apply the canonical projection $\pi : C \to C/J$ and then somehow obtain $C \otimes C$ again, or that we need  to go from a tensor product $C \otimes C$ to a single instance of the space factored, $C/J$. and then to a tensor product $C/J \otimes C/J$ again?

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku not quite. You only have to look at the whole map $C\to (C/J)\otimes (C/J)$, forget about the middle term. Then this map maps $J$ to zero. And so it does factor through $C/J$, as it always is in such setup.

Comment: So, "to factor through a map that goes through these factors" actually means "to be equal to a map that goes through these factors"?

======

Edit: Oh, wait, I think I implicitly supposed that some of the maps were surjective, and so was confused by a map from $C/J$ to $C$. I think I understand now.

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku no, I wrote what it means. The author says that the **entire composition** $C\to C\otimes C\to (C/J)\otimes (C/J)$ factors through the other map. That's why I said "forget about the middle term", it is not that important. Perhaps that is what you miss.